# Laravel - Loading classes

Tags: php, laravel

There are questions on here and around Google asking about the same thing, but being a noob, I'm still not getting this. I'm using Laravel 4.

Trying to have a file for random classes. Doesn't load.

The class is in:

```
app/classes/Helpers.php
```

*Helpers.php:*

```
class Helpers {

    public function randomLowerCase($amount)
    {
        strtolower($str_random($amount))
    }

};
```

I've placed my classes in composer.json.

```
"classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/controllers",
    "app/models",
    "app/classes",
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php"
]
```

autoload_classmap.php:

```
'Helpers' => $baseDir . '/app/classes/Helpers.php',
```

And also ran

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I'm running the function in a UserController.php file in controllers, but I keep getting `Call to undefined function randomLowerCase()`

Comment: Are you running (instance of Helpers)->randomLowerCase()? It sounds like you're running randomLowerCase() without the class...

Comment: Do you call like this. 

`$helpers = new Helpers;$helpers->randomLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not instantiating an instance of the Helpers class before you call one of its methods. You'll want to do one of the following:

First, keeping your class as it is, you could create an instance in the controller and call your method on it:

```
// Controller
$helpers = new Helpers;
$helpers->randomLowerCase($str);
```

Or, you could make the method static and call it as a static method:

```
// Helpers.php
class Helpers
{
    public static function randomLowerCase($amount)
    {
        strtolower($str_random($amount))
    }

};

// Controller
Helpers::randomLowerCase($str);
```

The error you're getting is because you're running the randomLowercase *method* as if it were just a *function*; methods are functions attached to a class/object.

Comment: Tried both solutions, but the error is the same :( Am I loading it right with composer/autoload?

Comment: I'm a derp. Thanks :)